# Why do I need to set DISPLAY variable to 10:0?

Tags: putty, xorg, xming

I have a Win10 machine, with Xming 6.9.0 installed. I use Putty to connect to a remote Ubuntu 18.04 instance.

I see the following:

```
ubuntu:~$ export DISPLAY=:10.0
ubuntu:~$ xeyes
#xeyes is shown on my windows machine just fine.
```

However:

```
ubuntu:~$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
ubuntu:~$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

Why is `:0.0` failing? Values like `1:0` or `2:0` also fail.

Why do I have to use `10:0` and why do all the online guides show `0:0` as the value for `DISPLAY`?

Comment: X supports multiple displays. To use a specific one you must use its correct number. When you connected with putty that's the display that was made. 0:0 is usually the first display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use Putty to connect to a remote Ubuntu 18.04 instance.

And you have probably enabled X forwarding in putty.

> Why is :0.0 failing?

Because `:0` means "display number 0 on the remote machine", which is typically the X server running on the remote machine. But since nobody with a monitor is logged directly onto the remote machine (if the machine even has a monitor), this X server is not running. (And even if it was running, you don't want to display `xeyes` on the monitor of other people).

OTOH, X forwarding by `ssh` and `putty` picks one of the higher display numbers (typically starting at 10) on the remote computer to mean "this will be forward to the local X server". So when you connect to `:10`, you really connect to your local X server, so you can see whatever the client program that is connecting does.

And the `DISPLAY` variable is usually automatically set by the forwarding program, you don't have to set it manually.